# How to run script, save new function in OtherUsers

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

how can I run worksheet or just import some function into OtherUsers folder.
OtherUsers/something/functions . I have no idea how can I do this.

Propably it's very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the *privileges* you have on the database. Typically a user account will have abilities to create objects in their own schema, but not others.  You can query SESSION_PRIVS to see what privileges you have in your session. If you see (for example) CREATE TABLE, you can create tables in *your* account. If you see CREATE ANY TABLE, then you can create tables in *other* accounts.

If you have that privilege, then you would prefix your commands with that account, for example:

```
create table SOMEONE_ELSE.my_table ( x int );
```

Otherwise, it is a case of actually creating a connection with the details of that *other* user.

Hope this helps.